# Проблема в корректной работе flex блоков CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Всем привет, недавно начал изучать html/css и наткнулся на непонятную для меня проблему.Flex блоки несмотря на flex-direction: row и достаточное место для расположения горизонтально, все-равно выстраиваются вертикально. Снизу прилагаю скрин страницы с фрагментом CSS. Я недавно на сайте, но насколько понимаю конкретно для этого вопроса больше ничего не понадобится.
Крайне жду  вашего ответа, так-как действительно не понимаю в чем может быть проблема ¯_(ツ)_/¯

[image: Ограничение ширины с помощью контейнера, который я использовал во многих классах.]
[image: Ограничение ширины самих элементов, с пэддингом, для правильного расположения в сетке.]

Comment: у вас внутри features только один блок - container. Ему и задавайте необходимые стили.

Answer (score 1):

Мне очень помогла эта статья https://medium.com/@stasonmars/%D0%B2%D0%B5%CC%88%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-flexbox-%D0%B2-css-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B8%CC%86-%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-e26662cf87e0
Надеюсь и Вам поможет.